# Different One-time screens

Tags: java, android

I am Wondering about one-time screens. I'll need to use few one-time screens on my app.

First of all:

One-time screen, that SAVES user selection from 3 options (I use image buttons) and let him go further, but next time user comes to this activity, it opens the activity of the option that user selected earlier.

I know I need to use code like SharedPrefences and saving to SD-card/app memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should consider a simple state machine design.

Say you created an `Enum`, `ERuntimeState`, which has two components;

`enum ERuntimeState { INITIALIZE, BEEN_INITIALIZED; }`

You can view a useful example of saving data using `SharedPreferences` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example), if you need a reminder. When using `SharedPreferences`, you're able to query an existing storage flag for your application, and if a variable hasn't been set before, you can set it's default value. So, when the application first runs, you can use `SharedPreferences` to check for a saved instance of `ERuntimeState`, using `INITIALIZE` as the default that will be picked if there's no existing save data.

Once this is done, you can use the `ERuntimeState` you've fetched to configure what contents you want to load on your screen; this is where you can display your first-time launch interface. We have to make sure that once this state is entered, you use shared preferences to save an `ERuntimeState` value of `BEEN_INITIALIZED`, so you don't execute the initialization step again on your next run.

Of course, by defining this `enum`, we're not limited to just two states. Otherwise we'd just use a boolean, and that's inflexible.

As an aside, this might be quite hard to debug! You might want to make sure you *don't* save the flag in your initialization state whilst you're debugging, otherwise you'll have to keep clearing all of the application's cached data in order to emulate an initial launch.

Comment: Could you add an example if possible?